# Django Rest Framework: Update and delete current user without providing pk

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know a lot of people already asked about handling with current user but I couldn't find solution so I post this.

What I want to do is to get, put and delete current user without providing `pk`.
I want to set endpoint like `users/my_account`

My current code is here

```
class MyAccountDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And now I can get current user's info but when I try to update or delete the current user,

> AssertionError: Expected view MyAccountDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

How can I solve this?

## Update

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('users/my_account', views.MyAccountDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: are you taking `pk` in url? please post url line calling the view

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari No. I mean I set url like `api/v1/users/my_account`

Comment: please post your `urls.py`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you will need to override [get_object()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself) method in your `MyAccountDetail` view. For example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class MyAccountDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

You need to do that, because by default `get_object` method looks for `lookup_url_kwarg` or `lookup_field` in the URL, and from that it will try to fetch the object using `pk` or whatever you have configured in **lookup_field** or **lookup_url_kwarg**.

FYI, I have added a permission class as well, because without it, `self.request.user` will be an anonymous user, hence will throw error.